# Is there a conversion tool for video to rosbag file?

Tags: ros, rosbag, audio, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have some data stored as video (RGB images and audio). Has anyone created a tool to convert this into a ROS bag file, as two synchronized streams of images and sound? The application here is audio-visual integration.

If not, any code/functions/packages that'd be helpful to create such a tool?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9345/is-there-a-conversion-tool-for-video-to-rosbag-file?/) by [Angelica](https://answers.ros.org/users/166/angelica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of such functionality at the moment, although it should be fairly easy to write with the [Rosbag Code API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API) and the OpenCV read/write functionality [from video in the high gui](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html). This needs to be converted to a rosimage using the [cv_bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge). I'm also interested in writing a package that does this for video in both directions, so if you need help.
There is an option of doing this with rosbag play/record and a second image_saver node, but as far as I know there's no integrated solution.
For audio you could have a look at Morgan's [audio_capture](http://www.ros.org/wiki/audio_capture) stack.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2016-12-07**:
any news on this?